# Windows 10 camera won't go to correct resolution

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, resolution, usb-3, camera

A while ago, I made a camera based on a the Omnivision [OV7251](https://www.ovt.com/products/ov7251/) image sensor, and the [Cypress CX3](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/universal-serial-bus/usb-peripheral-controllers-for-superspeed/ez-usb-cx3-mipi-csi2-to-usb-5gbps-camera-controller/) USB3.0 camera controller. I wrote the firmware myself, and so I know that the camera only supports the resolution 640x480 x 16-bits per pixel.

**Background:**
Until recently, Windows would happily support this camera in its correct resolution. The Camera application would display the colours incorrectly because they're greyscale 16-bits per pixel, but at least it could see the correct resolution. To display the image correctly requires an OpenCV Python script using numpy to wrangle the pixels into the correct format for display.

**Problem:**
All of a sudden, without any changes to the camera's firmware, Windows now reports that the resolution is 320x240. This is the same in the Camera application, and in my python script. OpenCV also reports the wrong resolution. The Camera application does not offer the correct resolution in the list of available resolutions.

**Question:**

- Could a recent Windows update have cause this?
- Is there some deep setting in the registry which I can change to force Windows to accept the correct resolution.

Windows 10 Home: 19045.3693
Build: 22H2
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

**A thought:**
Since my camera only supports 640x480, presumably Windows is actually rescaling the image somewhere!

**Added:**
Looking at the USB info, it seems as if the camera is actually reporting 320x240 as its resolution!?!?!

```
        -------- VS Uncompressed Frame Type Descriptor --------
---> This is the Default (optimum) Frame index
bLength                  : 0x1E (30 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Video Streaming Interface)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x05 (Uncompressed Frame Type)
bFrameIndex              : 0x01
bmCapabilities           : 0x00
wWidth                   : 0x0140 (320)
wHeight                  : 0x00F0 (240)
dwMinBitRate             : 0x0EA60000 (245760000 bps -> 30.720 MB/s)
dwMaxBitRate             : 0x0EA60000 (245760000 bps -> 30.720 MB/s)
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize: 0x00025800 (153600 bytes)
dwDefaultFrameInterval   : 0x0000C34F (4.9999 ms -> 200.000 fps)
bFrameIntervalType       : 0x01 (1 discrete frame interval supported)
adwFrameInterval[1]      : 0x0000C34F (4.9999 ms -> 200.000 fps)
```

On another Windows 10 PC (version 1909, build 18363.1556) the camera works correctly. And interestingly, the USB descriptor is correct:

```
        -------- VS Uncompressed Frame Type Descriptor --------
---> This is the Default (optimum) Frame index
bLength                  : 0x1E (30 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Video Streaming Interface)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x05 (Uncompressed Frame Type)
bFrameIndex              : 0x01
bmCapabilities           : 0x00
wWidth                   : 0x0280 (640)
wHeight                  : 0x01E0 (480)
dwMinBitRate             : 0x1D4C0000 (491520000 bps -> 61.440 MB/s)
dwMaxBitRate             : 0x1D4C0000 (491520000 bps -> 61.440 MB/s)
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize: 0x00096000 (614400 bytes)
dwDefaultFrameInterval   : 0x0001869F (9.9999 ms -> 100.000 fps)
bFrameIntervalType       : 0x01 (1 discrete frame interval supported)
adwFrameInterval[1]      : 0x0001869F (9.9999 ms -> 100.000 fps)
```

I also notice that the camera's name is different between machines:

The working machine reports the correct name: Cypress CX3-UVC - Camera
The non-working machine reports the wrong name: USB Composite Device - Camera

I wonder if the root of the problem is some kind of USB descriptor caching?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to uninstall the USB device using Device Manager, then disconnect and reconnect the camera.

Presumably this causes Windows to clear some kind of cache, and re-fill it with the correct USB descriptor.